# Convert txt file to tab in word document

Tags: excel, powershell, ms-word

Hello I have severals text files, *.txt files. They contain some information those I want to write in a tab inside a word document.

The tab is specific, some informations, must be copy in specific cell.

The text file use ';' and '\n' as separator. I have no idea why am I supposed to do this.

For example my text file will look like that :

```
NAME;Lipsum_name;
TITLE;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.;

DESCRIPTION;Quisque a arcu non diam dapibus sodales. Nunc blandit egestas diam, in maximus orci congue ut. Pellentesque sit amet ante a neque molestie rutrum.;
```

The informations must be copy in a word document, in a tab, which must look like this :

```
__________________________________________________________
|  TEST :Lipsum_name                                     |
|________________________________________________________|
|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.|
|________________________________________________________|
|Description    |Quisque a arcu non diam dapibus sodales.|
|               |Nunc blandit egestas diam, in maximus   |
|               |orci congue ut. Pellentesque sit amet   |
|               |ante a neque molestie rutrum.           |
|_______________|________________________________________|
```

In word it must look like the following screen :
[image]

I can't copy my datas to online converter, and I have only Powershell as tool for making the convertion but I have no idea how I can do. Perhaps I can use Excel, convert my txt file to CSV and then open it with excel and convert it to word ?

Answer (score 0):

#Powershell-Convert-TXT-to-DOCX:

```
$Text_Files = Get-ChildItem 
'c:\Users\userName\Desktop\FolderName\*.txt'
$Text_App = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application

Foreach ($File in $Text_Files) {
$TextFile = $Text_App.Documents.Open($File.FullName); $Name=($TextFile.FullName).replace('txt', 'docx'); $TextFile.SaveAs($Name, 16); $TextFile.Close();$Press_Enter = New-Object -com "Wscript.Shell";$Press_Enter.sendkeys("{ENTER}")}
```

Comment: On Windows 7, I have to write $TextFile.SaveAs([ref]$Name, [ref]16), else it does not work. But It only copy the content of the text file in a word. How can I copy datas in a format table ?